# Testing webgl with different random inputs

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am new to webgl so wrote a small program i.e. just to roll a ball along a string. So i want to test my program with random inputs and check if it is working or not.
I checked different links about "How to test webgl application" but didn't find any productive information. So please suggest me some way how to test my webgl project.
I am not at all interested to doing manual testing, so please suggest me some automation if any exists

Comment: How or what did you want to test as such, what do you mean with random inputs?

Comment: Random inputs are like different sizes of ball, varying length of rope like that.

Comment: I think your after this <script src="data/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

Comment: Not sure what you mean by testing. [Selenium works](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)

Comment: Ya i know selenium too but using selenium we can test functionality and regression testing right. So as of my example we can not see whether a ball of radius 300 is passing on given thread or my browser is allowing a thread of length 200 etc. Can we check the above described using selenium???